# AS3 shooting bullets to cursor from centre of character position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a top down shooter game. I've got my character moving. All I want to do next is make a bullet shoot from the center of my character to the direction my cursor is at. How would i go about doing this? 
I'm really struggling to think of the code i need to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will involve simple vector math. [There are tons of resources online about this.](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=as3%20bullet) Here's the basic gist:

1) First, calculate the angle (in radians) between your character and your target (in this case the mouse location). You can use [`Math.atan2()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2()) to perform this calculation.

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - playerY, mouseX - playerX);
```

2) Next, use that angle to create a vector (x,y delta) which represents the direction of travel for your bullet. You use [`Math.cos()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#cos()) and [`Math.sin()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#sin()) to compute the `x` and `y` value:

```
var speed:Number = 5;
var vector:Point = new Point(Math.cos(angle) * speed, Math.sin(angle) * speed);
```

3) Now you can update the bullets position each frame by that vector:

```
bullet.x += vector.x;
bullet.y += vector.y;
```

4) And if you want to make your bullet sprite point in the direction of travel, convert that angle to degrees and set the bullet sprite's `rotation`:

```
var degrees:Number = angle * (180 / Math.PI);
bullet.rotation = degrees;
```

Note that for the purpose of the math here, 0 degrees is considered to be right-facing along the x-axis, not up-facing like you might naturally think of 0 degrees (at least I do). **What this means is your sprites unrotated orientation should be facing right-ward.**